# How to exclude elements with namespaces - XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm getting input request with different namespaces like 'pn', 'tmn','pn2','pn3'..I have to get only elements which have namespaces 'pn2','pn3' and exclude the rest of the elements with other namespaces. How should I write this in XSLT ?

Here is my sample incoming request:

```
 <soap-env:Envelope
xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<Details actionCode="04">
<Info>123</Info>
<ID>ABC12</ID>
                        <pn2:Address
                        xmlns:pn2="http://www.blah2.com/"
                        >Address</pn2:Address>
                        <pn3:City cityID=" " scID=" " ID=" "
                        xmlns:pn3="http://www.blah3.com/"
                        >City</pn3:City>
                        <tmn:City cityID=" " scID=" " ID=" "
                        xmlns:tmn="http://www.blah.com/"
                        >City1</tmn:City>
                        <Address>       
                            <pn2:PermAddress xmlns:pn2="http://www.blah2.com/"
                             >Address1</pn2:PermAddress>
                            <tmn:Street StreetID=" " scID=" " ID=" "
                             xmlns:tmn="http://www.blah.com/"
                            >Street1</tmn:Street>
                            <pn:Estate StateID=" " SID=" " ID=" " xmlns:pn="http://www.blah1.com/"
                             >Estate</pn:Estate>
                            <pn3:Place xmlns:pn3="http://www.blah3.com/">Place</pn3:Place>
                        </Address>  
                       </Details>
                     </soap-env:Body>

</soap-env:Envelope>
```

XSLT I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="Details//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Details//@*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

I'm able to remove namespaces but not elements in my XSLT.

Comment: 1. Please fix your examples to be well-formed XML documents. 2. Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: Sorry. Please check now. I'm using 1.0 XSLT version.

Comment: What should be the result of the transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- exclude text nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri()) or starts-with(name(), 'pn2:') or starts-with(name(), 'pn3:')]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

A smarter way might be to ignore the prefixes and base the selection on the actual namespace URIs - i.e.:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri()) or namespace-uri()='http://www.blah2.com/' or namespace-uri()='http://www.blah3.com/']">
```